# Link behind image doesn't work

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

We are working on a website.
However, we have for some unknown reason trouble with the links.
When you are not on the homepage of the site, you can click on logo in the corner and then you should go back to the homepage, the index.php.
This is the code. Do we do something wrong?

```
 </a>

 <div class="navbar-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="top-nav">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <!-- Logo Starts -->
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="image.png" alt="logo"></a>
          <!-- #Logo Ends -->
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-    target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>


        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right scroll">
            <li><a href="#add-mop">Mop Toevoegen</a></li>
            <?php
              if($ip == '****') {
                echo "<li ><a href='#'>Login</a></li>";
              }
            ?>
          </ul>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to use an absolute link instead of the relative one and see if the bug persists.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more detailed, what "does'nt work" means?

Comment: What happens when you click on the link right now ? Does it take you to a `not found` page or what ?

Comment: @MatthiasS. If you click, nothing happens. When we hover over the image, below in our browser we see the right link. But it doesn't open the page we want

Comment: @Taurus Nothing happens. When we hover over the image, below in our browser we see the right link. But it doesn't open the page we want

Comment: Have you checked your Browserconsole for Errors?

Comment: @MatthiasS. Yes and we have no errors.

Comment: @WesleytJ Are you sure that you are not redirecting yourself from index.php to the current page as soon as you click the link ? I once had this occur with some PHP login functionality i think, it did confuse the hell out of me and seeing that you previously had a PHP tag (before i removed it), i believe it is possible that this could be your issue as well.

Comment: @WesleytJ Just curious, did you find the bug ?

Comment: @Taurus Weird, I thought I made a comment explaining that it was fixed. Yeah it's fixed. Guess the code was okay, but somewhere in a css file, there was some sort of line that shut down all clicks to other pages.

Comment: @WesleytJ The only way this could be possible is if the `pointer-events` property was used, but if that property is used, the link will not appear in the left-bottom side of the page (in Chrome) when you hover the mouse over it. Do you know what property was causing that?

Answer (score 0):

Is anchor tag `css` `display: block; ?` Check it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. No it isn't

Comment: Please do not use answers to ask clarification questions. [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
href='./index.php'
```

Maybe it is not picking up the address of the file correctly.